# Allow POST to google cloud functions but not GET?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-functions

So I'm writing an internal API with Google's cloud functions and we're going to allow only authenticated internal service accounts to access that function.
We have some security issues and I was wondering if it's possible to allow for example everyone to make POST calls but limit the service accounts that can make a GET call.
Is this possible?

Comment: Two methods: Use an external service such as API Gateway or in your code detect the HTTP Request Method and return `405 Method Not Allowed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) to set different level of security on different endpoints and different verbs.

If you want to authorize only some identities on a special verbs, you need to filter that in your code, no product allow you that out of the box (maybe [Apigee](https://docs.apigee.com/) but it's quite expensive).